# Ruby daemon for Rails 3.2.12 app was not loaded - File path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-daemons

We are using a script (ruote_daemon_starter) in a rails 3.2.12 engine (commonx) under "config/initializers" folder. This script is meant to call another script in the same engine under "/script" folder to start a daemon. Please see below details on both scripts.

I am getting from passenger the error of `No such file or directory` as below:

```
 //weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/www/btop/releases/20131108030053/config/environment.rb:5)
    ruby: No such file or directory -- ../../script/daemon.rb (LoadError)
```

==== config/initializers/`ruote_daemon_starter.rb` =======

```
 #!/usr/bin/env rub
    exec "ruby ../../script/daemon.rb start "
```

==== script/`daemon.rb` =======

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'daemons'
require 'logger'
file = Dir.pwd + '/ruote_worker.rb'
options = {
    :app_name   => "ruote_worker",
    :dir_mode   => :normal,
    :log_dir    => "pid",
    :dir        => 'daemon',
    :log_output => true,
    :backtrace  => true,
    :multiple   => false
}
Daemons.run(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'ruote_worker.rb'), options)
```

The rails app is running on ubuntu 12.04.